# calculate linear regression curve (as described on tradingview docs) TALIB

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, algorithmic-trading, ta-lib

I'm trying to figure out how to implement this function using python (pandas/numpy/talib)

reading tradingview docs:

> Linear regression curve. A line that best fits the prices specified over a user-defined time period. It is calculated using the least squares method. The result of this function is calculated using the formula: linreg = intercept + slope * (length - 1 - offset), where length is the y argument, offset is the z argument, intercept and slope are the values calculated with the least squares method on source series (x argument).

I'm extremely new in this area so don't judge me (haha), so I tried reproduce the same function using talib functions and came to this:

```
lri = ta.LINEARREG_INTERCEPT(df, timeperiod=length)
lrs = ta.LINEARREG_SLOPE(df, timeperiod=length)
lrc_res = (lri + lrs) * (length - 1 - offset)
```

but the result is not what is expected

can someone help me with this?

Comment: so why `(lri + lrs) * (length - 1 - offset)`, shouldn't it be `lri + lrs * (length - 1 - offset)`

Comment: ta-lib has ta.LINEARREG() func that do what you want. And you may check its sources here: https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/ta_LINEARREG.c#l200  Make sure you're passing right timeperiod